# PHP reuse: What are the differences between "include files" and "functions"?

Tags: php

What are the differences between "include files" and "functions" for reusing code in PHP?

I can enumerate 1 difference: when using a function, the caller script don't have access to the function local vars but when including the includer script has access to the local vars of the included script.

What are other differences?

When should i use "functions" and when should i use "include files"?

For DB connection which one is usually used?

Comment: The purpose of maintaining functions across multiple files is to keep control of the site. Sometimes this is referred to as a MVC pattern, where one file serves the model, another the view, and lastly the controller. When I design, I generally have an interface for my database that defines the functions and variables within. Then, I develop abstract classes that implement the interface for core functionality. Finally, I'll extend the abstract classes for specific view types, such as videos, images, posts.

Comment: what i know about include and function is that function can be create single time and call again and again on same page script.but include is use when one page script want use in another pages.

Answer (score 2):

Functions are callable blocks of code. Usually created by the developer when that certain block of code is used multiple times. Instead of writing the same code in multiple places, you create a function and call it when needed.

Also, some developers create functions to make a certain task distinct in the code for readability and understandability. They use functions as "labels" as to what a certain block of code does. For example, I'd create a `readFile()` function for a certain block of code that reads files.

Includes on the other hand "merges" a file into the calling file as if it were coded into that file. This makes whatever was declared in the other file available in the current file in the scope that called it.

---

As for what to use, you use both.

To separate DB connection code from the current file, I'd create a DB Class in another file (like `dbcon.php`) containing all the properties and methods (functions) needed to interface with the DB.

Then, in the file that needs the DB connection (like `index.php`), it should use `include` to "merge-in" the file containing the DB Class for `index.php` to use the class definition.

Answer (score 1):

It seems an obvious question, but it's interesting anyway to share our experiences.

Inclusion of configuration files (constants i.e.) should be done with `require_once`. Because without it your system cannot works (require), and it should be included only one time (once).
So... `class`, `DB configuration`, `constants` and core files should be inserted by `require_once` and not with `include`, because if some file missing, it throws a fatal error and stop execution, preventing errors chain.

So, when we can use `include`?

`include` should be used for `inclusion` of part of code more more complex (with other inclusion for example) and with part of code that's no mandatory or essential for your system. You can think, for example, to an inclusion of one module for the view. (include a php file that process a tpl file). I thinking when I work on system with other developer: some part are shared (i.e. Database) and some part are local. If I modify something in shared part that causes a failed inclusion for other developers, it not cause a fatal error for they. (it's just an example)

Now: when I should use `function` instead?

When you write a lot of function you can use ONE single file included (or, better, required) and call one of this function when you want. Besides the code inside all functions is encapsulated preventing annoying conflicts with other part of code (and believe me: it happens very often and it's not always easy to find the error)

Benefit: one single file for many functions, and all code encapsulated.